# Progresión aritmética en python

Tags: python, lista

Tengo este ejercicio donde de una lista debo tomar los valores de tres en tres para obtener la sumatoria de una progresión aritmética, sin embargo en la calculadora arroja los resultados correctos pero en el código no. Con la lista de ejemplo de abajo los resultados correctos serían 21 y 30, pero en mi código me arroja 14 y 30. Agradecería sus ayudas al respecto...

## Progresión aritmética

```
lista = '5 2 3 3 0 10'

lista_new = lista.split()

lista_nueva = []
for n in range(0, len(lista_new), 3):
    lista_nueva.append(lista_new[n:n+3])



lista_enteros = [[int(n) for n in lista_new] for lista_new in lista_nueva]
print(lista_enteros)


valores = []

for sublista in lista_enteros:
    progresion = (sublista[2] // 2) * ((2 * sublista[0]) + (sublista[2] - 1) * sublista[1])
    valores.append(progresion)


resultado_finales = ' '.join(map(str, valores))
print(resultado_finales)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error lo tienes la línea en la que defines 'progresion'. Estás utilizando el operador '//' que devuelve la división entera entre sublista[2] y 2; por lo tanto, al hacer 3//2 te está devolviendo 1.

Para evitar eso, simplemente edita esa operación a una sola barra para que tenga en cuenta los decimales del resultado.

```
progresion = (sublista[2] / 2) * ((2 * sublista[0]) + (sublista[2] - 1) * sublista[1])
```

Comment: Gracias @Daniel Sánchez!